# more than currency input field

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery

I have this input tag where you put the total of your receipt :

```
<input type="text" name="currency" id="currency" class="text-input" onBlur="this.value=formatCurrency(this.value);"   />
```

The Javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function formatCurrency(num) {
    num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g,'');
    if(isNaN(num)) {
        num = "0";
    }
    sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
    num = Math.floor(num*100+0.50000000001);
    cents = num % 100;
    num = Math.floor(num/100).toString();
    if(cents < 10) {
        cents = "0" + cents;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length-(1+i))/3); i++) {
        num = num.substring(0,num.length-(4*i+3))+','+num.substring(num.length-(4*i+3));
    }
    return (((sign)?'':'-') + '$' + num + '.' + cents);
}

</script>
```

Users can only enter receipts more than $10.00 bucks, how can I set that on my script? Also they need to know they can not enter currency less than $10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather from your question I think you are looking for something like this. Basically if we have a valid entry such as `$100.00` we continue, return true etc, else if we have something that looks like an int or float we can reformat this and recurse the function, else hint user for of vaild entry

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

foo.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
    var val = e.target.value;
    var err = document.getElementById('err');
    var errMsg = 'please enter a value $10.00 or greater';
    var patt = /^\$\d+\.\d{2}$/;    
    var amount = parseInt(val.replace(/\$|\./g, ''));

    if (val !== '') {
        if (patt.test(val)) {
            if (amount < 1000) {
                err.textContent = errMsg;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('suc')
                    .textContent = 'processing request';
            }
        } else if (typeof amount == 'number' && !/[a-z]/g.test(val)) {
            if (/\.\d{2}/.test(val)) {
                e.target.value = '$' + (amount / 100);
            } else {
                e.target.value = '$' + amount + '.00';
            }
            arguments.callee(e);
        } else {
            err.textContent = errMsg;
        }
    }
});
```

here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JBR53/9/)

Comment: hey thanks for the demo, why the scrip doesn't get $2.33 for example. if i add 2.33 to the text box it change to $233.00.. i try changing the pattern script but it give $2.33e+22 no idea why

Comment: Hi, sorry I think I have worked out most of the bugs though if you type in say 2.333 it is mutated to 23.33 :( I may have edited the code in the answer but perhaps didn't update the fiddle (I have done this now). **you may need to refactor and tighten up some of the logic**, if you have any problems doing so maybe ask in another question. I believe the problem you have described was because `amount` would include decimals as though it has been multiplied by 100 so that needed to come off see `(amount / 100)`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a validation function when submitting the form to test if the value is below a threshold, such as:

```
function validate()
{
  value = document.getElementById('currency');
  if (value <= 10.00)
  {
    return false
  } else
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

You could also apply this to the onblur event, but my preference is to present validation errors when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to parse a string, convert it nicely into dollars and cents, and reject it if it's less than 10. There's a much nicer way to do that:

```
function formatCurrency(num) {

    // Remove the dollar sign
    num = num.replace("$", "");

    // Change the string to a float, and limit to 2 decimal places
    num = parseFloat(num);
    Math.round(num * 100) / 100;

    // If its less than 10, reject it
    if(num < 10) {
        alert("Too small!");
        return false;
    }

    // Return a nice string
    return "$" + num;

}
```

At the end, are you trying to return `-$99.94` if the number is negative?

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure what you were trying to do at the end. Give the function I posted above a go.